# Are the cpli and ctli tests time senstive(i.e. is it needed to test right away in order to get accurate results)?

Tags: biochemistry

I'm sending the blood samples to a lab and this takes some time until the actual testing.

Some information on the tests.

TLI : http://www.vcahospitals.com/main/pet-health-information/article/animal-health/trypsin-like-immunoreactivity/405

CPLI : https://www.vetstream.com/canis/Content/Lab_test/lab00522

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From doing a bit of research, I quote

> The various analytes have different stability in serum. **Serum TLI and
>   PLI are stable for up to 2 weeks at room temperature.** However, serum
>   folate shows limited stability at room temperature. Therefore, serum
>   samples for folate analysis should be kept at 4ºC for not longer than
>   48 hours, but freezing is preferred. Furthermore, folate is light
>   sensitive and samples should be stored in the dark or wrapped in foil ([reference](http://vetmed.tamu.edu/gilab/service/faq)).

So, it should be fine if the tests are conducted in two weeks.